# Access object property via array

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

How can I simplify this structure:

```
$properties = $rs->$domains[0];
$dn = $properties[0]->distinguishedname;
```

Because PHP gives error on such construction:

```
$dn = $rs->$domains[0][0]->distinguishedname
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work, or rather none of them should work.

To access a member of a object using the `->`operator you don't need to use the `$` twice, it should throw an error or warning of some kind as far as i know.

```
$properties = $rs->$domains[0];
$dn = $properties[0]->distinguishedname;
```

Should be:

```
$properties = $rs->domains[0];
$dn = $properties[0]->distinguishedname;
```

Likewise:

```
$dn = $rs->$domains[0][0]->distinguishedname;
```

Should be:

```
$dn = $rs->domains[0][0]->distinguishedname;
```

That's the only problem I can see with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Only looking at it quick it seems as though your code should work as long as the data is actually there. Perhaps you try to fetch **distinguishedname** from a **domain** that has no **properties**?

What does the php error say? Do a *var_dump* on your data structure to see that it actually contains the data you expect that it does.